# SOQL query to retrieve PermissionsModifyAllData from all Permissions sets with its assignments

Tags: soql

The SOQL query should return PermissionsModifyAllData, the name of PermissionSet, and its assigned users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about querying the [PermissionSetAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm) object like this?

```sql
SELECT PermissionSet.Name,
    PermissionSet.PermissionsModifyAllData,
    AssigneeId,
    Assignee.Name
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working as expected. I am trying this query on tooling API, I want a response like, One PermissionSet JSON object should have all of its Assignees. But this query is returning them in different JSON Objects.